# Porting issue in visual studio 2015 - _flag is not a member of _iobuf

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, msvc14

I am porting existing VC12 compiler compatible code to VC14 (visual studio 2015) and I am facing code break problem.

Sample program to reproduce issue:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
#define mybuffer(param)       ((param)->_flag & (_IOMYBUF))

int main()
{
    mybuffer(stderr); // I don't understand what is the purpose of this line.
                      // So, facing issue in replacing this code statement.
    return 0;
}
```

On visual studio 2013: above program works absolutely fine.

On visual studio 2015: above program gives compilation error.

Error   C2039   '_flag': is not a member of '_iobuf'

Error   C2065   '_IOMYBUF': undeclared identifier

***Analysis:***

In VS2013, wchar.h has following:

```
struct _iobuf {
    char *_ptr;
    int   _cnt;
    char *_base;
    int   _flag;
    int   _file;
    int   _charbuf;
    int   _bufsiz;
    char *_tmpfname;
    };
typedef struct _iobuf FILE;
```

*Where as in VS2015, in file: corecrt_wstdio.h*

```
#ifndef _FILE_DEFINED
#define _FILE_DEFINED
typedef struct _iobuf
{
    void* _Placeholder;
} FILE;
#endif
```

Can you please help me in suggesting a fix for above error?

Comment: See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1419290/file-is-not-a-member-of-iobuf-bug. Basically the old code was poking into undocumented parts of an implementation detail. If you could say what the original code was trying to actually achieve, we may be able to help find a way to do that that is allowed.

Comment: The connect.microsoft.com link is invalid :( `Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired`

Comment: were you able to fix the issue.